# Norm of a linear operator $A:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$, with both $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ equipped with $l^1$-norm.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I've got a linear operator $A:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$, and I'm to find its norm (given that $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are both equipped with the $l^1$ norm).

So I'm already convinced that $\|A\|$ is (when considering $A$ as a matrix operator) the column of $A$ with maximum $l^1$-norm.  But I'm hitting a wall in my proof.

Here's what I've got so far.

Let $\hat{A}=\max_{1\le i\le n}\sum_{j=1}^m \left| A_{j i} \right|$, the column of $A$ with maximum $l^1$ norm.  Then we have that 
                    \begin{align*}
                    \|A\|&=\sup_{\substack{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \\ \|x\|_{l^1}=1}}\|Ax\|_{l^1}\\
                            &= \sup_{\substack{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \\ \|x\|_{l^1}=1}}\sum_{j=1}^m \left|\left(Ax\right)_j\right|\\
                            &= \sup_{\substack{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \\ \|x\|_{l^1}=1}}\sum_{j=1}^m \left|\sum_{i=1}^n\left(A_{ji}x_i\right)\right|
                \end{align*}
                Notice that (when $\|x\|_{l^1}=1$),
                        $$ \left|\sum_{i=1}^n A_{ji} x_i\right|\le \sum_{i=1}^n \left|A_{ji}x_i\right|\le\sum_{i=1}^n\left|A_{ji}\right|\|x\|_{l^1}=\sum_{i=1}^n\left|A_{ji}\right|$$
                So then 
                        \begin{align*}
                        \|A\|&=\sup_{\substack{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \\ \|x\|_{l^1}=1}} \sum_{j=1}^m\left|\sum_{i=1}^n A_{ji}x_i\right|\\
                        &\le \sup_{\substack{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \\ \|x\|_{l^1}=1}}\sum_{j=1}^m\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\left|A_{ji}\right|\right)\\
&= \sup_{\substack{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \\ \|x\|_{l^1}=1}}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^m\left|A_{ji}\right|\right)\\
&\le \sup_{\substack{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \\ \|x\|_{l^1}=1}}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\|\hat{A}\|_{l^1}\right)\\
&= n\cdot\|\hat{A}\|_{l^1}
                    \end{align*}

But I know that my inequalities aren't strong enough, since clearly the column with maximum $l^1$ norm will be less than the sum of each of the column's $l^1$ norms.  Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x = \lambda_1 e_1 + \ldots + \lambda_n e_n$. Then, for $x$ to be a unit vector, $\sum_i | \lambda_i | = 1$. Let $a_i$ denote the $i$-th column of $A$.

Then, $\lVert A x \rVert = \lVert A (\sum_i \lambda_i e_i) \rVert \leq \sum_i \lVert A ( \lambda_i e_i)  \rVert = \sum_i |\lambda_i| \lVert a_i \rVert \leq \max_i \lVert a_i \rVert$ for any unit vector $x$ (since the $\lambda_i$'s are bounded between $-1$ and $1$). So, $\lVert A \rVert \leq \max_i \lVert a_i \rVert$.

Note that$\lVert A x \rVert = \max_i \lVert a_i \rVert$  is achieved when $x = e_k$ where $k$ is the column with highest 1-norm.  So, $\lVert A \rVert = \max_i \lVert a_i \rVert$.

Comment: Great answer, thank you!

Comment: @MöbiusDickus Since you're new here, the appropriate thing to do when someone answers your question is to click the "check" mark next to the answer to accept it.  This does multiple things:  Marks the question as being answered,  and gives reputation.

Comment: @Alan I'm aware of this.  There is a timer on accepting an answer (perhaps not on you, but I have one as a new user).